# Cisco, No dot1q tunnel mode on switchport

Tags: cisco-catalyst, tunnel, qinq, switchport

The problem is:
I can not find a QinQ(a.k.a. double vlan tagging or dot1q tunnel) feature in the following cisco switch:
WS-C4510R+E, SUP8-E with WS-X4748-UPOE+E line card installed.

The Cisco Feature Navigator says it should be in my platform.

I'm pretty new at the IOS-XE, the only IOS supported by this HW.

I've upgraded ios-xe to the:
cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.03.08.01.E.152-4.E1.bin
And also I've tried:
cat4500es8-universal.SPA.03.03.00.XO.151-1.XO.bin
cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.03.09.01.E.152-5.E1.bin
No luck.

May be I have some license or feature enable(mechanism) in IOS-XE Problem.
My current license looks like:

```
Switch#show license all 
License Store: Primary License Storage
License Store: Dynamic License Storage
StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days 
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 3 days 
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: Low
StoreIndex: 1 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA accepted
      License Count: Non-Counted
StoreIndex: 2 Feature: ipbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days 
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 4 days 
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 3 Feature: ipbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA accepted
      License Count: Non-Counted
StoreIndex: 4 Feature: lanbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA accepted
      License Count: Non-Counted
StoreIndex: 5 Feature: apcount  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days 
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 4 days 
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
      License Count: 0/0
      License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 6 Feature: apcount  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: 0/0
```

I haven't find the sdm template command there also.

```
Switch#show dot1? 
dot1x
```

First of all i've tried to:

```
configure terminal
    int gi 1/1
    (config-if)#swi mode ?
          access        Set trunking mode to ACCESS unconditionally
          dynamic       Set trunking mode to dynamically negotiate access or trunk mode
          private-vlan  Set private-vlan mode
          trunk         Set trunking mode to TRUNK unconditionally
    (config-if)#int te 5/5
    (config-if)#swi mode ?
          access        Set trunking mode to ACCESS unconditionally
          dynamic       Set trunking mode to dynamically negotiate access or trunk mode
          private-vlan  Set private-vlan mode
          trunk         Set trunking mode to TRUNK unconditionally
```

And nothing about:

```
switchport mode dot1q-tunnel
```

and even

```
show dot1q?
% Unrecognized command
```

Because I'm not setting up QinQ in the first time. I've checked at Cisco Feature Navigator to be sure my IOS-XE supported it. Yes cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.03.08.01.E.152-4.E1.bin supports QinQ and even Selective QinQ. I've tried to configure QinQ at line-card and SUP8-E - no such command.

```
    (config)#default int te5/5
    Interface TenGigabitEthernet5/5 set to default configuration
    (config)#int te 5/5
    (config-if)#switchport 
    (config-if)#switchport mode access 
    (config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
    (config-if)#switchport nonegotiate 
    (config-if)#switchport mode ?
          access        Set trunking mode to ACCESS unconditionally
          dynamic       Set trunking mode to dynamically negotiate access or trunk mode
          private-vlan  Set private-vlan mode
          trunk         Set trunking mode to TRUNK unconditionally



    (config)#default int te5/5
    Interface TenGigabitEthernet5/5 set to default configuration
    (config)#int te 5/5
    (config-if)#switchport 
    (config-if)#switchport mode access 
    (config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
    (config-if)#switchport nonegotiate 
    (config-if)#switchport mode ?
          access        Set trunking mode to ACCESS unconditionally
          dynamic       Set trunking mode to dynamically negotiate access or trunk mode
          private-vlan  Set private-vlan mode
          trunk         Set trunking mode to TRUNK unconditionally
    (config-if)#switchport vl?
          % Unrecognized command
```

I think the main problem is Inactive ent license:

```
StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days 
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 3 days 
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: Low
```

Comment: What have you tried to enable QinQ on a switch interface, e.g. `switchport mode dot1q-tunnel`?

Comment: I'm asking for what you have tried. You don't show that in your question. Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: Sure I've tried it. No such command for line card (int gi1/1) and SUP8-E(Int Te5/5). IOS-XE doesn't even understand show dot1q ?

Comment: That command was an example. What all have you tried? Edit your question to include everything you have tried, and any messages that arise from your attempts. You need to give us everything.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: So, you didn't disable DTP or set an access VLAN on the interface?

Comment: How do you know if you haven't tried? The command may not be available until you meet all the conditions necessary to use it.

Comment: As long as I've said earlier: that doesn't matter. My whole IOS-XE doesn't know anything about dot1q tunnels according to `show dot1q? % Unrecognized command`

Comment: So, you just intend to be hardheaded and not even try something simple? You won't get very far asking for such help here.

Comment: I've tried to configure It all the ways i know it should be configured and all the way you told me. Those command are not exist on the switch. There is some logic and programmatic inheritance and coding... If, for example, you didn't implement the class, you can't create the object. Thus, on my mind, if you don't see `show dot1?` command, something is wrong with that feature.

Comment: You claim that the switch meets all the requirements for this, but I don't think it does: "_802.1Q requires WS-C4948E, WS-C4948-10GE, ME-4924-10GE, WS-C4928-10GE, WS-C4900M_." As I wrote, "_The command may not be available until you meet all the conditions necessary to use it._"

Comment: Where have you gotten those requirements from? According to the Cisco Feature Navigator cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.03.08.01.E.152-4.E1.bin support selective QinQ.

Comment: From everything I can see, unless you specifically set `switcport mode access` or `switchport mode trunk` to unconditionally set the the mode, then use `switchport nonegotiate` to disable DTP, you cannot use QinQ. DTP must be disabled on the interface. Also, the interface cannot be a layer-3 interface, so you must have the `switchport` command enabled, not disabled with the `no switchport` command. An interface with DTP enabled may not have the command for QinQ.

Comment: Selective QinQ that you say this supports uses the `switchport vlan mapping <vlan-id> dot1q-tunnel <outer vlan-id>` command on a trunk interface. Verify with the `show interfaces <interface-id> vlan mapping` command.

Comment: Did you follow the specific sequence in something like http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15-1/XE_330SG/configuration/guide/config/tunnel.html - calls for setting an access VLAN before the switchport mode dot1q is available in the parser.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the exact sequence according to my IOS-XE version command reference manual... I think problem in license.

Comment: You said that the feature navigator says that it supports selective QinQ, but does it say it supports the traditional QinQ that you are trying to configure? Selective QinQ is only used on trunk ports by VLAN mapping. Did you try Selective QinQ?

Comment: Good question. Yes it Does. But It was really difficult to find how Cisco named QinQ and what that names mean. By the way, solution found.
Thank you for your help, folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As QinQ is ISP feature the key was in Not in Use entservice license state:

```
show license all
...
StoreIndex: 1 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
    License Type: PermanentRightToUse
    License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA accepted
    License Count: Non-Counted
...
#configure terminal
    #(config)#license boot level entservices !
#reload
```

Just After reload(No license were entered!):

```
show license all
    ...
    StoreIndex: 1 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
    License Type: PermanentRightToUse
    License State: Active, In Use
    License Count: Non-Counted
    ...
show log
    ...
    *Dec 26 01:20:03.606: %C4K_IOSSYS-6-IMAGELEVEL: Supervisor booting in image level 'entservices'
    ...
```

All commands needed for QinQ feature(and much more) became available:

```
#show dot1q-tunnel ?
    interface  specify an interface
    |          Output modifiers
    <cr>
(config)#int gi 1/1
    (config-if)#switchport mode ?
    access        Set trunking mode to ACCESS unconditionally
    dot1q-tunnel  set trunking mode to TUNNEL unconditionally
    dynamic       Set trunking mode to dynamically negotiate access or trunk mode
    private-vlan  Set private-vlan mode
    trunk         Set trunking mode to TRUNK unconditionally
```

By the way, all interface configuration commands are available in any switchport mode, just error can occurs:

```
(config)#int gi 1/1
    (config-if)#no switchport
    (config-if)#switchport mode dot1q-tunnel 
        Command rejected: Te5/5 is not a switching port.
```

And all show command available:

```
#show dot1q-tunnel 
    dot1q-tunnel mode LAN Port(s)
    -----------------------------
    Gi1/24
    Te5/5
```